# MoveFileWithProgress throws "The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive" – why?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I have:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveFileWithProgress(
    string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
    CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
    int dwFlags);

public enum MoveFileOptions 
{
    MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED = 0x2
}
```

And calling it with:

```
if (!MoveFileWithProgress(source.FullName, destination.FullName, cpr, (int)options)) {
  throw new IOException(new Win32Exception().Message);
}
```

Where: `options` is `MoveFileOptions.MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED`

It works fine when moving in the hard drive. But when I try moving to a Flash-drive, I get: `The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive`.

Why?

Comment: Can we see the actual call to MoveFileWithProgress that you are making?

Comment: @M.Babcock `if (!MoveFileWithProgress(source.FullName, destination.FullName, 
                cpr,
                (int)options))
            {
                throw new IOException(new Win32Exception().Message);
            }`

Comment: Please update your answer rather than posting code as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DllImport` is incorrect. Your function has only 4 parameters, but the [real function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has 5. Presumably what is happening is that `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` is being passed to `lpData` and is ignored. The `dwFlags` parameter is just whatever happens to be sitting on the stack.

Fixing your p/invoke will probably solve the problem. Also, `dwFlags` should be unsigned.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveFileWithProgress(
    string lpExistingFileName,
    string lpNewFileName,
    CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine,
    IntPtr lpData,
    uint dwFlags
);
```

With this correct you need to decide what to pass to `lpData`. Since you appear not to be using it at the moment, it doesn't really matter and `IntPtr.Zero` seems the obvious choice.

Comment: Although you would think he would use the same call from [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8596367/719186).

Comment: @LarsTech Hmm, perhaps the code in the Q is not the real code and just a copy/paste error. Would seem surprising to delete a parameter entirely.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I thought when [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says a parameter is optional that it would be like overloading in C# - that one could leave a parameter out entirely. It seems it just means that one can pass an  `IntPtr.Zero` (in this case).

Comment: Yes that's right, optional parameters like in C# are always a language construct but the native language of Windows is C and that has no optional params or overloading. So optional win api params are invariable pointers and `NULL` means that you are omitting the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

From this [Microsoft | Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978739.aspx) page, it says:

> The file cannot be moved to a different disk drive at the same time you rename it using the Rename command.

Try renaming the file before moving it.

Comment: I'm "renaming" it from `@"c:\users\Me\t.txt"` to `@"f:\t.txt"`. Doesn't seem to be a real rename. How would I do it differently?

Comment: @ispiro Couldn't tell off hand without seeing more code to try to reproduce it.  Could be a generic error if something is not right with the flash drive.  Any chance the file already exists on the flash drive?  What happens if you just try normal File.Copy() for the same two files?

Comment: And I get the same error when moving to a CD. (and `File.Move()` works fine there as well.)

Comment: [Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.movefilewithprogress) is showing a different signature for the MoveFileWithProgress call than you are using.  Something to try.

Comment: @LarsTech: You are right, the code above is missing `IntPtr lpData` as the parameter before `dwFlags` -- it's very likely this is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps moving a directory?

According to the [documentation for MoveFileWithProgress at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis added):

> When moving a file, lpNewFileName can be on a different file system or volume. If lpNewFileName is on another drive, you must set the MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED flag in dwFlags.
>
> **When moving a directory**, lpExistingFileName and lpNewFileName must be on the same drive.